# Retrieving Google Authorization Code through OAuth2.0 in Java

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, authorization, google-api-java-client

I am working on a desktop project that requires Google Authorization for Google Calendar API using OAuth2.0. The language used is java.

Currently to authorize the project, I have to open the browser using java.swt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(url), click the "accept" button, copy the authorization code in the redirected page and paste it in my application. And the user has to close the webpage manually. Quite troublesome.

Is there a better, more user-friendly approach to achieve this authorization procedure? The ultimate procedure I want to achieve is only that the application opens the authorization page, the user clicks "accept", the page closes itself automatically and the software is authorized. I have seen this kind of procedure in other applications. It's just that I don't know how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a callbackURL. I would recommend using a java library like [Scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) to accomplish this - there is a good [getting started page](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/wiki/getting-started) and plenty of examples.

**EDIT 1**
Here is a sample for setting up a callback url

```
String apiKey = "your_app_id";
String apiSecret = "your_api_secret";
OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                          .provider(FacebookApi.class)
                          .apiKey(apiKey)
                          .apiSecret(apiSecret)
                          .callback("myApp://oauthcallback")
                          .build();
```

You would need to open an embedded browser in your desktop app, and go to the oauth url as given by OAuthService. Once the user has approved your app, the embedded browser will be redirected to your callback URI. You'll need to detect this and then extract the oauth info included in the callback.

I've never done this through a desktop application (it was always within a servlet/jsp - web app). But if you search for how to detect redirect on a URI in windows, hopefully you will find some examples.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried the example given in Scribe pages and found that when constructing the Verifier I still need to go and copy the code from the browser right? The example I just tried is this: https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/TwitterExample.java Is it possible for me to eliminate this copy and paste procedure because It just looks too stupid for an application to have things like this. Thanks again for your response. :)